# отправка post через таблицу

Tags: php

мне нужно отправить форму в которой находится таблица

```
<form>
    язык - файл - описание
    язык - файл - описание
    язык - файл - описание
    язык - файл - описание
    ....
</form>
```

как можно постом поймать все значения полей `язык` + отследить что их `n` множество и ко всему эти поля между `<td></td>`

Comment: а таблица то статичная или генерируется php?

Comment: генерируется на php

Comment: если твои данные берутся из БД, то всё проще простого: все "языки" скорее всего у тебя уже в массиве, надо их только "вытянуть" оттуда, а сколько их посчитать функцией `count`, которая подсчитывает количество элементов массива.

Comment: если у них атрибут `name` одинаковый то count($_POST['язык']) даст мне длину массива

Comment: нет, тебе нужно считать не ПОСТ данные, а когда генерируется таблица, до отправки формы

Comment: а полученные данные уже вставить в input или textarea и отправлять вместе с формой, как то так

Comment: а сто стороны файла обработчика как я поймаю поля с одинаковым неймом после этого

Comment: так зачем же - каждому "языку" input не нужен, вставляй их все в один через запятую или массивом тоже можно отправлять POST, а кол-во их - в другой input

Comment: точно, надо их в 1 инпут какой- то скрытый запихнуть. Вот оно